# How to count the number of SYN, ACK, or SYN-ACK in a second?

Tags: networking, ddos, intrusion-detection, intrusion-prevention

I want to make a DDoS SYN Flood Detection, so i need to count the number of SYN, ACK, or SYN-ACK packet per second.

Answer (score 1):

I believe

```
netstat -s
```

will be your friend.

If you are looking for a switch level service, you can use sflow/netflow to collect data and send them to the collector.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tcpdump` or `shark` for capturing the filtered packets and count them as you want.